# Framing a basement column with off-center 2x6s?

Tags: basement, framing, column, framing-fasteners

I'm going to frame a column in my basement, but I need it to include a few outlet boxes (one for power, and one for speaker).  All the videos I've watched show 2x4s being ramset into the columns dead center. That makes sense, but I need room for the outlet boxes.

It appears as though using 2x6s off-center plus drywall will allow the perfect amount of room for the outlet boxes. I've mocked up my thoughts on this and want to double check that I'm not missing some good reason why this is a bad idea.

Is this okay?

[image: column-mockup]

Side note: I don't have a ramset. Are there alternatives, or do I really need to spend $40 for the hardware/tools for a single column?

**Update:** the answer below helped me a lot! I was able to build it without needing any special tools, and it worked wonderfully. It feels incredibly sturdy with NO wiggle, and turned out looking quite nice too, if I do say so myself :)  I ended up just using wood, and not adding drywall on top. This causes a bit of an issue with needing a shallow box, but it looks great, and saved a TON of time.
[image]

Comment: I think you could probably assemble the lumber, slip it in place and throw a tube of construction adhesive at it, wait a day or two and drywall/wire. It's cosmetic, so there really isn't any good reason to nail it to the column. For that matter, you don't need 2x lumber, either, unless you want it extra-fat.

Comment: maybe use wider, shallower  boxes with mud-rings, and yeah 3/4" timber is plenty thick enough. this could reduce the size of your finished column considerably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You idea will work fine. No need for ramsets, there are self-drilling tapping screws that will hold those in place very well.

[image]

Image courtesy of Uturn fasteners

Big box stores or any good hardware store will have these.

Comment: These worked perfectly, thank you very much!